# Query Only Showing First Returned Value

Tags: google-sheets

I built a form to collect data in a couple different categories and I'm having trouble getting it to return all the values associated if multiple submissions are made with one person. I can query this looking for all the people that like "pie" for example and it's fine but to look at all the desserts that a person likes it's only returning the first result.

The live form is more complicated that I'm showing so it's unlikely I can change the data collection since that will probably break something that's currently working.

The expected result for "Lucy" should be Pie, Waffles, and Cake but it's only returning "Pie."

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l2WA1fj-TWHGZZMsJpD6Gb85MFlixSzTPdwtJPi3MVc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The original logic I was using was this: =IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(A:B,"Select B where A like '%"& D2 & "%' order by B"),", ", FALSE)))

The solution I was given by Ballow was this: =ARRAYFORMULA(trim(transpose(split(concatenate(filter(B2:B34,A2:A34=D2)&","),","‌​))))

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
=join(", ", filter(B2:B7, regexmatch(A2:A7, D2)))
```

Or, if you want to have every value in it's own row:

```
=transpose(split(join(", ", filter(B2:B7, regexmatch(A2:A7, D2))),", "))
```